# Allocate extra memory to the character array C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, string-concatenation

I have this problem where I have a string and I pass it to the function as a character pointer.

```
 void test(char * str) {
    ....
 }
```

where str = "abc". Now I want to add few extra characters to the end of this string without creating a new string. I do not want to use strcat as I do not know how many characters I am adding to the end of the string and what I am adding. I was trying to work with realloc but it does not work as the str is allocated on stack.

Is there any way I can increase the size of the char array dynamically?

UPDATE :
I was asked a question which involved this in my interview. I was asked to do it without using additional space. So if I allocate memory using malloc I am technically using additional space right?

Thanks

Comment: `void test(char ** str){…; *str = realloc(...); assert(*str);}`

Comment: @Eddy_Em using realloc like that is dangerous. Always use a temporary variable first, before copying it in. Also, what happens if you pass in a pointer created by alloca, or a character array, like the OP seems to be requesting?

Comment: How is `str` initialized in the calling function? It is something like `char str[] = "abc";`?

Comment: I cannot realloc as I my string is declared as char str[] = "abc". It is not malloc-ed.

Comment: @Fox then you must make a copy of it.

Comment: Sorry I wanted a solution in C++

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, question have too little information. BTW, temporary variable will cause memory leaks.

Comment: @Eddy_Em no, you use a temporary variable to ensure that realloc succeeds before re-assinging the reference passed in the parameter.

Comment: In C++ you should avoid c strings and certainly malloc and realloc.

Comment: @Fox, if you want a solution for C++ you should use `std::string` container instead of array of chars.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, I agree. I just didn't think that str maybe a char[].

Comment: If C++ use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: So, an interviewer asked you to "append to a string allocated on stack, given _that_ function signature?" Either they just wanted to reject you, or they expected you to tell them they're crazy. Even if you use additional memory, that function prototype can never work.

Comment: @Shahbaz No the question was to replace a character in the string..I used this function signature. I could have malloc-ed in the first place but I just assigned it on stack. So I just wanted to know if it still constant space if you create a new sting and delete the old string or if there is any other way.

Comment: @Fox You can't delete the old string. There's no way of passing the new one back, and the pointer may not be to memory that you *can* free.

Comment: @fox, I see. If the function was supposed to replace a character in the string (by another character), you don't need to resize the string and the function signature is alright.

Comment: @Shahbaz What do you mean by don't need to resize the string. I want to replace the character by 3 characters I do need to resize the string. and the question was to do it in O(1) space.

Comment: @fox, that's why I said _replace a character in the string **(by another character)**_. In your case then again no, it's not possible unless you allocate the memory dynamically and renew the string.

Comment: @Shahbaz Ok .. Thanks ..  But one final thing I wanted to know is If I am allocating new memory it is not considered O(1) right?

Comment: @fox, since you are _first_ allocating new memory, copying over, and _then_ freeing the previous memory, then no, it's not O(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using C++ - then stick to `std::string` and forget the whole deal with `char *`.

However if you wish to use the `char *` for strings, then allocate a new character array and `strcpy()` from one string to another. Do not forget to deallocate the original `char *` memory to avoid memory leaks.

> I was asked a question which involved this in my interview. I was asked to do it without using additional space. So if I allocate memory using malloc I am technically using additional space right?

How can you increase the length of the string without adding additional space?

Comment: If I use you char* suggestion is it still considered constant space in an algo?

Comment: Ex -- http://www.careercup.com/question?id=16018673 where space complexity asked is O(1). But there you will need to create a new string..

Comment: @Fox ah no - that's not what it means. It means that you cannot create a new string - you have to modify the same string. Which means you must have enough memory allocated to the string in the first place, but you cannot create additional string.

Comment: @Fox think of it along the same lines as "swap contents of two integer variables without using a third variable"

Comment: How will you allocate enough memory in the first place if you do not know how much space is required?

Comment: @Fox that time you allocate atleast 4KB of string. Or use `std::string`.

Comment: Exactly I don't want to create a new string but just increase the size of the old string...that is what I was asking. But it seems it is not possible with out creating a new string and deleting the old string. So was wondering if it still considered O(1) if I create a new string and delete the old one ..

Comment: @Fox then you are pretty much constrained by the language compiler and standards itself.

Answer (score 3):

No, especially if the string is allocated on the stack. The stack space is fixed at compile-time. You must either allocate more space initially, or allocate a new array with more space and `strcpy` it over.

Comment: No need to equivocate. Your answer is equally applicable to C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

You must `delete` the old string and allocate a new one with `new` with the length you want.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted so harshly, but it *is* correct if we're talking about C++ here. Unfortunately, the OP doesn't appear to be using C++, he simply mis-tagged his question.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, I didn't downvote, but I completely understand it. Besides the other problems such as the string not being `new`ed in the first place, the fundamental problem with this solution is that `str` is an argument of type `char *`, if you delete it, with the current function prototype, you have no way of letting the user know there is another pointer in town.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no. A dynamic variable/array cannot be resized up. The problem is that another variable, or even another call frame  could be immediately following the variable in question. These cannot be moved to make space as there may be pointers to these objects elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Perhaps you mean a _static_ array cannot be resized? Because `realloc` does exactly what you say is impossible, i.e., resizing a dynamic array.

Answer (score 0):

```
void test(string  &str) {
    ....
    str += "wibble";
 }
```

Seems to work for C++

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using realloc(not to be done on stack) or strcpy(uses extra buffer space) you may store the new values from the byte right after the input string. In the simple example below, I begin with "abcd" and add three z's at the end in the function fn.

```
void fn(char *str)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    memset(str+len, 'z', 3);
    str[len+3] = 0;
    return;
}

int main()
{   
    char s[] = "abcd";
    printf("%s\n", s);
    fn(s);
    printf("%s\n", s);  
}
```

Output:

```
abcd
zzz
```

This way can be extended to adding different strings in front of original one.